# XMLHTTPREQUEST with .ajax to access a server file

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

the data returned from the api in json format

```
[
{
"hours":
{
    "monday":
    {
        "open_time":"11:00:00",
        "close_time":"22:00:00"
    },
    "tuesday":
    {
        "open_time":"11:00:00",
        "close_time":"22:00:00"
    },
    "wednesday":
    {
        "open_time":"11:00:00",
        "close_time":"22:00:00"
    },
    "thursday":
    {
        "open_time":"11:00:00",
        "close_time":"22:00:00"
    },
    "friday":
    {
        "open_time":"11:00:00",
        "close_time":"23:00:00"
    },
    "saturday":
    {
        "open_time":"11:00:00",
        "close_time":"23:00:00"
},
"sunday":
{
    "open_time":"11:00:00",
    "close_time":"21:00:00"
}
}
}
]
```

this is my javascript on my localhost in my html

```
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', "http://example.co/?method=get&search=hours&type=place&place_id=1&format=json", true);
    req.responseType="json";
    req.send(null);
```

I've tried using .ajax and .get. I'm just no retrieving the data right. I figured using XMLHTTPREQUEST would be a better alternative. 
My Question is
1. How would i go about using XMLHTTPREQUEST to retrieve the json data?

Comment: If you're not using jQuery, you have to call `JSON.parse()` to convert the response from JSON to a Javascript object.

Comment: i am using the latest version of jquery

Comment: You're not using jQuery to perform your AJAX request, though, you're using the low-level `XMLHttpRequest`. If you use `$.ajax` and specify `dataType: 'json'` it will automatically parse the JSON for you.

Comment: Never mind, I just checked the XHR documentation, and I see that setting `responseType` performs a similar function. But `json` isn't supported by most browsers. See the compatibility table at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: So you need to call `JSON.parse()` in your callback function.